# sqlalchemy-migrate ImportError: No module named versioning

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I started to learn Flask by following Miguel Grinberg's tutorial. Im getting this error while trying to run migrate script in my Flask application. When I import it through the Python shell, though, it goes works. Updating SQLAlchemy and sqlalchemy-migrate packages changed nothing. Anybody have any suggestions how I can fix it?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./migrate.py", line 3, in <module>
    from migrate.versioning import api
  File "/home/alexxmagpie/PycharmProjects/flasktest/migrate.py", line 3, in <module>
    from migrate.versioning import api
ImportError: No module named versioning

Name: sqlalchemy-migrate
Version: 0.10.0

Name: SQLAlchemy
Version: 0.7.9
```

[migrate.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxFIv.png)

Comment: Please include your code in the question. Don't link to a screenshot of it.

Comment: You have a module named `migrate`. Inside it you try to import the module `versioning` inside the `migrate` package. `migrate` isn't a package. `versioning` would have to live somewhere else.